# How to change the value of an input?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that has input, text and select elements added dynamically.

The ID of the form is `#user-form` and I need to change the value of the `input/select/text` elements that appear within this form.

One of the form items is hidden on page load which is why I included `input:hidden` in my select.

An example of the HTML output for one element looks like this:

```
<input id="slider-coll" class="enq-form-input form-text" type="text" maxlength="128" size="10" value="" name="slider_coll">
```

My current code, using jQuery, looks like this:

```
sliderForm.find('#user-form').find('.enq-form-input, .enq-form-select, input:hidden').change(function() {
    inputValue = $(this).val();
    console.log(inputValue);
    $(this).val(inputValue);

  if (catchValue && feetValue) {
      calculateAmounts(catchValue, feetValue);
    }
});
```

I defined `catchValue` & `feetValue` as global variables outside of the change function.   This form also uses the jQuery slider plugin.

`Console.log` returns the correct value, but I can't get the actual input value to update.

`calculateAmounts` is an ajax function that needs to fire whenever any value is changed.

Right now `catchValue` & `feetValue` are returning false, even when `console.log` returns the correct value.

I'm probably missing something easy, anyone know how to fix this?

* Per Nerdwood Request****

`calculateAmounts` is below, but it is not the problem. It works when I test it against a single forced change. My issue is that the values of the inputs are not updating.

```
function calculateAmounts(catchValue, feetValue) {
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/calculateAmounts/ajax',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: ajaxCalcAmountsCompleted,
      data: {
        catchValue:catchValue,
        feetValue:feetValue
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't update anything you set for the input the same value it already contains.

Comment: Please show the contents of the `calculateAmounts()` function.

Comment: Uby - I think that you are on the right path. This might be stupid planning on my part. I first create the variables catchValue and feetValue as global variables outside of the change function. I dont change the value of the variable to the new value within the change function.

Answer (score 0):

```
inputValue = $(this).val();
console.log(inputValue);
$(this).val(inputValue);
```

why are you changing the input value to itself?

also, you said `catchValue` and `feetValue` are false, so `calculateAmounts` won't be called.

also, `sliderForm.find('#user-form')` tries to find the form within itself, `$(#user-form)` is enough because an id is unique in the document

you say you are trying to change the inputs' values, yet `.change` is an event called whenever the value is changed.

did you mean something like this?

```
$('#user-form').
    find('.enq-form-input, .enq-form-select, input:hidden').
    each(function() {
        inputValue = $(this).val();

        $(this).val("new text"); //whatever new value for the input

        //do something with inputValue ..

        if (catchValue && feetValue) {
           calculateAmounts(catchValue, feetValue);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I think the main problem is a lack of understanding on my part. Every time the value of an input field changes I need to call the ajax function and that function take two parameters each of which should hold the changed value. I thought that this had to be done using the change function (so that it fired every time the value changed).